# Overflow x label MatPlotLib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this bar graph but the X labels that are long keep overflowing into the other label. Is there a way I can create more space or cause a line break when it is doing this?
Below is the part of the code that accounts for the graph

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = tweets_df.plot(kind='bar', x='name', y='tweet_volume', fontsize=7, width=.5)
ax.set_xlabel('Hastag')
ax.set_ylabel('Tweets w/ Hashtag')
plt.xticks(rotation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can use `rotation=90` instead of `rotation='horizontal'` or if you want to keep `horizontal` and truncating values,

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5

ax = tweets_df.plot(kind='bar', x='name', y='tweet_volume', fontsize=7, width=.5)
ax.set_xlabel('Hastag')
ax.set_ylabel('Tweets w/ Hashtag')
plt.xticks(rotation='horizontal')

labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels([label[:N] for label in labels])

plt.show()
```